# Trying to create a simple encryption program

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to create a simple encryption program that can be easily encrypted and decrypted nothing fancy.
so far I have the basic input set up:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test {
 private static Scanner inp;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Password");
    int n = inp.nextInt();
    System.out.println(n);
    if(n!=234) {
        System.out.println("Denied Acess");
    } else { 
        System.out.print("Password Accepted");
    }
    System.out.print("Input Text to encrypt: ");
    String m = inp.next();
    System.out.println(m);
 }
}
```

I'm just starting out in java and this is my first real program as I am teaching myself it is slow going :P (I only started a few days ago)

Anyway I need a way to take a mass input and have a mass out put where I can target letters/numbers and have them changed to a corresponding preset string

**example:**

> input text:  Hello
>
> output text: {aeh}{wer}{qds}{qds}{cxv}

but I would also need a way to read the output code when input and have it output the original input which I don't know if I can do that with multiple digits unless I could do a if else nest such as

```
if(dig1==a) {
 if(dig2==b) {
  if(dig3==c) {
System.out.print("a")
} else {
 if(dig1==b) {
  if(dig2==c) {
   if(dig3==d) {
System.out.print("b")
} else {
if (dig1==c) {
 if (dig2==d) {
ect.
```

but even then I don't know how to automatically set it so the program can automatically assign each digit/set a variable and then have it out put the corresponding string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read your question as: you already have code that translates the String

```
"He"
```

into

```
"{aeh}{wer}"
```

And now you are asking how to reverse that in a reasonable way.

One option: use a `Map<String, String>` to make your mappings easily available to you:

```
Map<Character, String> encryptionMappings = new HashMap<>();
encryptionMappings.put('H', "{aeh}");
encryptionMappings.put('e', "{wer}");
... and so on: one put() for all characters you wish to support
Map<String, Character> decryptionMappings = new HashMap<>();
decryptionMappings.put("{aeh}", 'H');
... as above, just "reversed"
```

Now you can write code like:

```
String encryptMe = "He";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Character c : encryptMe.toCharArray() ) {
  builder.append(encryptionMap.get(c));
}
String encrypted = builder.toString();
```

The above iterates a string character by character, and then uses the Map to lookup the string that replaces each character.

De-crypt is pretty similar: you can iterate a list/array of Strings:

```
String[] deecryptMe = new String[] { "{aeh}", "{wer}" };
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String str : deecryptMe) {
  builder.append(deecryptionMap.get(str));
}
String decrypted = builder.toString();
```

(please note: the above is meant as "pseudo code"; I didnt run it through a compiler; so beware of typos. The idea is that this shows you what classes are around, and how you could make use of them to simplify what you are doing)

Beyond that: you dont need to put down the decryption map manually - you could just *build* it at runtime, by iterating the other map and taking the information from there.

Finally: one core part here is to adhere to the *single responsibility principle*.

Update: encryption/decryption of strings ... is **one** side. You should not **mix** that with "Scanner" work. Meaning: start with a method that takes a String and returns an encrypted String. Test that. Then create a method that decrypts. (you can do nice things such as checking that `decrypt(encrypt("whatever")).equals("whatever")` for example.

And when all of that works; then you write your code that asks the user for input; and gives you strings; which you **then** feed into those existing methods.

Comment: i dont yet have the incryption code yet but i have the basic input set up and im stll working on making the codex i just chose som erndom sequences as an example but i do want each digit to correspond to a 3 digit code

Comment: so i would iterate the mapings at the start of the code as: map(string, string); map(string, String);.... and then call the map with the code you wrote and it would output the code? what would i have to identify the scanner as for the code to work thouhg?

Comment: could you give me an example of how i would implement multiple mappings please

Comment: I put in a bunch of updates. But please understand that I am not your personal tutor, I wont go on answering all your follow on questions. As said; this is **a lot** of ideas to get you going. Read them carefully, and try things step by step; and read the javadoc for all the classes I am using there* carefully*.

Comment: thank you i apreciate it :) i cant afford a tutor so this site is my best option :) i learned the basics from a tablet app XD

Comment: my ide is pegging the code as being 100% invalid is there a an import i need to do? uup i put it in the wrongspot but its still not recognizeng "hashmap"

Comment: That is why I said: search for those class names and read about them. You need java.util.* for starters. Hint: make sure that your code currently compiles. Then add these things **one** by one. Dont just paste all my code there. As said: you will need time to "built up" things here! Finally: thanks for the quick reactions!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Map cannot be resolved to a type
 HashMap cannot be resolved to a type

 at test.main(test.java:5)

Comment: ik lol i test and comple my code after each section and the java.util.* fixed it thanks for the help

Comment: @Heyo13579 `encryptMe` ... has content that is going to be encrpyted; and the result of that ends up in the `encrypted`. Same for the `decryptMe` array that contains some "encrypted" letters; they end up within `decrypted`.

Comment: I have it set like that the input works but the output says thatthe variabke encrypt is not use and whats the link to the javadoc i cant find it.... fixed it i had the print line set in the wrong bracket set... but i still cant find the javadoc u sent me

Comment: For any javadoc: turn to Google and type something like java hashmap ... And start looking..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132439/discussion-between-heyo13579-and-ghostcat).

Comment: Final comment for this week, as I will take days off: it looks to me like you are overburdening yourself. The things you keep asking are really super basic stuff. My tip: Google for Java tutorials Oracle... And read/work through those. There is a nice one for collections (lists, maps,...) for example. Then: try to find people who are close to you... And work with them face 2 face. Stackoverflow can't be a replacement for you studying all the basics first. Anyway good luck for your next efforts!

Comment: I appreciate the help but i learn best when i code "on the fly" liek this it helps to ingrain it better and the program is done except for one line that has an error